# Is it true that $n/\log(n)$ is approximately $\log(n/\log(n))$ for large enough $n$

Tags: calculus, asymptotics

Someone wrote this on a homework assignment I'm grading:

> $n/\log(n)$ is approximately $\log(n/\log(n))$ for large enough $n$

Is there an easy way to see it as true or false?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No since $\frac{\frac{n}{log{n}}}{\log{\frac{n}{log n}}}\rightarrow \infty$

Comment: After writing down that right arrow, writing "for $n$ sufficiently large" is incorrect.

Answer (score 3):

No, it's like asking if t is approximately log(t) when t is really big, which is like asking if p is approximately 2^p when p is really big, and that's obviously wrong.

Answer (score 1):

We can just define $m=\frac n{\log n}$.  This function is monotonic when $n$ is large enough.  Then the claim is that $m \approx \log m$, which is badly wrong.